# "Запретил к воплощению свои произведения..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> На тот момент Сэлинджер ещё был жив и, конечно, не следил за
>   репертуаром малой сцены Театра имени Пушкина, но всем было известно,
>   что знаменитый отшельник, который спрятался в горах штата Вермонт и не
>   выходит на связь с внешним миром, категорически запретил к воплощению
>   свои произведения в театре и кино.

Как быть?

"...Наложил категорический запрет на воплощение своих произведений в театре и кино"? Ой как мне не нравится!

Оставить как есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...категорически запретил к воплощению... /...наложил запрет на воплощение... - по-моему, проблема не снимается. Или не трогать, оставить как есть, или предложить автору заменить на менее пафосное, например:

"категорически запретил экранизировать и ставить на сцене свои произведения".

Answer (score 3):

А если так: категорически **запретил  воплощать** свои произведения в театре и кино.

Непонятно усложнение грамматической конструкции.

Comment: Видимо, неуместна _формализация_ выражений с этим метафорическим словом: возникает ассоциация с неким бланком "запрета на воплощение". Формализация делает навязчивым и буквальный смысл слова _воплощение_: **осуществление в реальности** того, о чём написано.